# No current text sorting works for numbers

Tags: sorting, text, formatting

In the DOS-era, text sorting when it comes to numbers use to work normally. ASCII order was correctly taken into account by any editor. Example: the list 100,1,20,3,10,2 would of been arranged in the correct order: 1,2,3,10,20,100. Now-days any text editor seems to disregard numbers (and special characters), resulting in something like: 1,10,100,2,20,3, which is practically a mess. This is also valid for other characters.
How can I make a correct sorting now-days ?

Note: I'm trying to use this to put many IP addresses in order.

What sort or any editor does:

```
103.207.39.0 
124.248.228.0 
125.75.132.0 
13.107.6.0 
136.243.202.0 
139.217.27.0 
14.139.200.0 
14.53.187.0 
144.76.109.0 
148.251.204.0
```

This is the desired output:

```
13.107.6.0 
14.53.187.0 
14.139.200.0
103.207.39.0 
124.248.228.0 
125.75.132.0 
136.243.202.0 
139.217.27.0 
144.76.109.0 
148.251.204.0
```

Comment: Tested already, it does not.

Comment: Nope, tested on W7 and it does not work. Note: I'm trying to use this to put many IP addresses in order. Perhaps it only works for integers. I added the note to the question.

Comment: The dos / windows console "sort" utility is a text sort (no numeric conversions). In the case of a text file with one integer per line, for equal lines, the shorter line is considered smaller, such as "1" versus "100". I'm not sure if the line length is use or sort just relies on the fact that "return" (hex 0D) or "line feed" (hex 0A), are less than alphanumeric characters. A period is hex 2E and also less than any alphanumeric character, so it should sort as wanted, but it would help if you could post a few lines of sample input. (I deleted prior comments).

Comment: Added sample in the main question.

Comment: Even the old DOS sort utility would not sort the way you want since it's a text base sort, so "100.0.0.0" would be sorted before "11.0.0.0". You could make a modified copy of the text file that puts in leading zeroes, such as changing "14.53.187.0" to "014.053.187.000", or create your own sort program that converts the 4 numeric fields to actual binary numbers to compare.

Comment: I remember doing it directly on old MSDOS editors.

Answer (score 0):

Open your file of IP addresses in Notepad++. Do a regex Find-and-Replace:

Find what: `(?:^|(?<=\.))\d(\d)?(?=\.|$)`

Replace with: `\x20(?1:\x20)$0`

Make sure the search mode is "Regular expression" and click Replace All.

Now sort the lines using **Edit > Line Operations > Sort lines Lexicographically Ascending**

Now do another regex Find-and-Replace in order to get rid of the spaces:

Find what: `\x20`

Replace with nothing: make sure the search mode is "Regular expression" and click Replace All.

source: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/14354/can-i-sort-ip-addresses-in-numeric-value